# How to keep in sync the Outlook 365 Calendar for MacOS with the iCloud calndar

Tags: ms-office, calendar, office-365

I'm on MS Outlook 365 for MacOS. I use it for a custom IMAP account. Sometimes I receive meeting invites and those are saved to the Outlook 365 calendar. Is there a way to sync them with one of my iCloud calendars?

Comment: Why not using your Outlook calendar on the macOS Calendar app? Or adding your Outlook account through System Settings? What have you tried and in which ways didn't it work?

Comment: I have the calendar M on iCloud and the calendar O in MS Outlook. I tried to import the calendar M from the calendar tab in Outlook, but there is no way to do it. I did not find a way to import the calendar O in the calendar app of macOS.